# jQuery dialog - Internal html hyperlinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have searched the forum and the internet for an example on how to move around in a dialog box using hyperlinks. Maybe this is an old and answered problem but here goes:

I am loading the html content from either a database or a file. This content contains a lot of internal hyperlinks to various divs etc. in the html code. None of them are working, not even links to move to the top of the page within the dialog.

My question is simply if this, at all, is possible to do? And if it is what am I doing wrong?

Simple html file example (htmlfile.html):

```js
function showFile(file){
     $.get(file), function(result) {
      if (result != undefined) {
       //Open the dialog here
                $(result).dialog({
                .
                .
                });
      }else{
              alert("Could not load content");
            }
     });
    }
```

```html
 <div id="top">
      <a href="#metar-tag">METAR</a>
      <div>
        <div>    
          --some html content --
        </div>
        <div id="metar-tag">
          --some html content --
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#top">Go to top</a>

      --more content--
    </div>
```

The dlg box is open with:

```
showFile("htmlfile.html");
```

This file is loaded ok in the dlg box but the link is not working.

Any suggestions is very much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: When you fill the divs with dummy content after click the hyperlinks if works but it is not work after ajax content then not work, that's meaning -I think- there is/are problem in the ajax content. isn't it?

Comment: After comparing the content in the file and after the load via ajax using the Chrome debugger, both are identical so I am not sure this is the problem.